# Java lambda toMap of Map<String, Boolean>

Tags: java, collections, lambda

I can't see why this fails;

```
Map<String, Boolean> iMap = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5").stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(k->k, Boolean.TRUE));
```

The error Message:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from T to K
    - The method toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K>, Function<? super T,? extends U>) 
      in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> k) -> {}, Boolean)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of the second argument to `toMap`?

Comment: Not a function. Got it, thanks.

Comment: Instead of `Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5").stream()`, you can use `Stream.of("1","2","3","4","5")` to express your intend directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) expects a `Function` for both parameters. You're trying to pass a `Boolean` instead. Try this:

```
Collectors.toMap(k->k, k->Boolean.TRUE)
```

Comment: Really? Collectors.toMap(k->k, v->Boolean.TRUE) doesn't read better?

Comment: @Nicholas It's misleading. `k` does not represent the key, it represents the stream element. Using `v` for the second parameter only propagates the confusion.

Comment: Darn, I'll get the hang of this yet. `Collectors.toMap(s->s, s->Boolean.TRUE)`